# Firebase insert with generated key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a root in firebase like in the  I am trying to enable user to delete an item on list. But user can give up his decision. When user give up this decision, I want to insert the deleted item again in the database. But, I want to insert with old firebase generated key, because I am using firebase push keys. Is that a bad practice. How firebase generate these keys? Does it checks every key on db and generate a new one? Is that any possibility, that key marked as removed and generated later for another item? Sorry for the language. It has been hard to express.

EDITED: I want to use the old key because, I am getting the data with orderByKey. I dont want to lose order.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How firebase generate these keys? Does it checks every key on db and generate a new one?

Whenever you use `push` on a Database Reference, a new data node is generated with a unique key that includes the server timestamp. These keys look like -`KiGh_31GA20KabpZBfa`.

Because of the timestamp, you can be sure that the given key will be unique, without having to check the other keys inside your database.

> Is that any possibility, that key marked as removed and generated later for another item?

No, it is not possible that two keys will collide, regardless of wether one has been removed or not.

> But, I want to insert with old firebase generated key, because I am using firebase push keys. Is that a bad practice

Unfortunately, you can't generate the same key twice by just using `push`. So, it is not possible to delete a node with a given key and then use `push` to insert it again at the same path with the same key, because `push` would generate a different and unique key.

Instead of this, if ordering by key is that important to you, and there's a possibility that a deleted node can be reinserted then I would recommend you to do one of the following :-

1. Either save the key on the client side when it's deleted from the database, and use it when you need to reinsert.
2. Or , maybe, have a "deleted-keys" path in your database and save the deleted keys there. Of course, with this approach, you'd need to store additional information to identify the data that the key corresponds to.

It all really depends on your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I already know the keys of that items. I am mapping them when I am getting the data. So, I know the deleted key and I can insert with it again. I really get the idea for the firebase keys. Thank you. :)

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Calling push() will generate a key for you.

If instead you use child(), you can determine they key/path yourself.

```
ref.child("yourvalue").setValue("setting custom key when pushing new data to firebase database");
```

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

Comment: I know, but I want to use old key. Because I dont want to lose order. I am getting the data with orderByKey(). Is there any possible future harm by using the old key as a new key?

Comment: you can get old of the old key from your request and then set it here it will do the job

Comment: I know it will do the job. I just want to know, its dangerous to use it by hand like this way.

Comment: i think so it is not a problem as firebase keys are part timestamp and part random char so its highly unlikley for two keys to be same .updated a blog link  in ans